# How to read a multiple line cell into R data frame

Tags: r

[example of the data I am trying to read into R data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgD6B.jpg)

Dear friends: 
I am trying to read the data, in which a single Excel Cell containing multiple lines, into a R data frame.  Ideally, I want to keep those multiple lines in a single spot in the data frame with some separators between these lines, such as |, ;, etc.

How could I do that?

The resulting file should be like this:

Patient Segment(s)***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_****Sponsor(s)*__PrimaryDrugs_Other Drugs

"Comorbid...| Diabetic...|Hypertensive..."**__*NIDDK*__***celecoxib***__**.....

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on how you access this data. If you export it to a CSV file the CR-LF's in the cell may break the lines so that there will be a need to read them in with `readLines()` and then reassemble them with `paste()`. On the other hand if you use a package that is designed to read individual cells, the line breaks may get incorporated into single elements. You should display the CSV output ... or explain how you planned on accessing hte XLS file and post a portion of it somewhere tha tpeople can get to.

On a Mac it requires ctl-opt-enter to put a cr-lf into a cell. If it is there, exporting produces a result that looks like this in a text editor

```
"there is 
a test of 
alt-ctl-enter
"
```

and which then looks like this with read.table:

```
read.table("~/test.csv", header=FALSE)
                                      V1
1 there is \na test of \nalt-ctl-enter\n
#plus a harmless warning about an incomplete line.
```

So it as a single character element in a vector. To replace the "\n" which is the <"cr-lf"> in R strings with "|" (pipes) use gsub:

```
 dat <- read.table("~/test.csv", header=FALSE)
 gsub("\n", "|", dat$V1)
#  [1] "there is |a test of |alt-ctl-enter|"
```

Comment: Simple wrapped text should copy into a single cell in the data.frame but Excel does not provide any indication of how the text is wrapped unless the lines are broken with Alt-Enter in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Exactly. I was unsure how such a cell would get exported and figured it was up to the questioner to provide a specific example for his particular case.